# :before doesn't inherit parent's width

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a text that morphs into bolder text on mouse over.

To achieve this I created invisible bold text (to give correct width to the container which would avoid jumping when the text changes its weight on mouse over) and I'm animating only `:before` pseudo element from `font-weight: 200;` to `font-weight: 700;`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ky55D/

Demo with text enabled: http://jsfiddle.net/ky55D/1/ (they don't match for some reason with or without `:hover`).

The problem is that the second word "Gravida" in my example goes to the next line instead of being placed on top of its parent. Adding higher `width` to `.link:before` helps but I have no idea what the proper width would be. `200%` works for 2 words. `300%` works for 3 words etc.

[image]

Any ideas if this can be fixed with just CSS?

Comment: why dont you simply transition the font in the tag itself (without :before psaudo)?

Comment: What OS/browser are you using ? I don't have this issue with Win7/Chrome-Firefox-IE10

Comment: @avrahamcool Because a word that changes its font weight becomes longer and it moves other elements on the website (next words like that). That's why I'm using this workaround to set it proper (maximum) width from the start.

Comment: @zessx Chrome/Win7 but it doesn't work also in IE10 and Firefox.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to define transitions for `.link:before` and `.link:hover:before` in a separate rule - defining them for `.link:before` will have them apply in the hover state automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change approach, according to the KISS paradigm :)

- Use a `transparent` `text-shadow` in normal state;
- Make it coloured in `:hover` state.

The text will appear bolder, but the overall width won't change, nor the words will be moved.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tQd6g/1/

---

Edit: add `display: inline-block;` to your `a` element as well, since now it is working as an `inline` displayed object, that is probably not what you want for your purposes:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ky55D/2/

Comment: Thank you for the solution but unfortunately the original font that I'm trying to use is like 1px wide when it's in `font-weight: 100;` state and it becomes very bold (like 10px) in `font-weight: 900;` state. That's what I would like to animate.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it: if you use `text-shadow` to make it bold, then you have no need to alter `font-weight` anymore; what am I missing ?

Comment: (1) It works only for 1px increment, (2) it doesn't consider the difference between `font-weight: 100;` and `font-weight: 900;` built in in the font. It's not as simple as adding outline to a letter. There are more differences between light and extra bold font variants. Maybe this works for Arial or Helvetica but not for fonts from: http://www.google.com/fonts/ (transformation from "Quicksand Dashed" to solid, bold Quicksand won't work). http://content.altfonts.com:81/img/Q/U/Quicksand-Dash-Regular0.png

Comment: Then I had (still have) not got what you need. Btw, I edited my answer with an hint that could resolve most of your issues. The fonts are still not aligned in a certain moment, but for 99% of the cases (of resizing) they are.

Comment: Thank you! I think that now it's exactly what I was looking for :)